# Metric space question in convergence

Tags: analysis

Suppose that we are given a point x and a sequence ($x_{n}$) in a metric space M,and suppose that $f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x)$ for every continuous,real-valued function f on M.Does it follow that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ in M?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Define $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(t)=d(t,x)$$

Then since $f$ is a continuous, real-valued function on $M$, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, i.e. $d(x_n,x) \to d(x,x) = 0$ which means that $x_n$ approaches $x$.

Comment: Thanks for answer,but if we get the function $f(x)=x^{2}$ with $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and we get the $x_{n}=(-1)^{n}$ then $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow 1=f(1)$ and $x_{n}$ not converge to 1.

Comment: @ΘάνοςΚ: You have shown that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ only for the function $f(x)=x^2$. You have to show that it is true for any continuous, real-valued function. Not just a particular one! For example, the identity function on $\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous, real-valued function that fails to have that property! Therefore, what you gave is not a counter-example to the statement.

Comment: I understand thank you :)

Comment: @ΘάνοςΚ.  You're welcome. :)